# Permanent and Present Address Database Design

Tags: sql, database

What is the correct way of adding address on the database?

I know that is common to separate it with another table if the user will have more than one address but in my case. I have limited the address for the user, I will only used permanent and present address with zip code. So what is the best approach? What I did is the I just put it together on users table

```
[users]
first_name
middle_name
last_name
permanent_address
permanent_address_phone
permanent_address_zip_code
present_address
present_address_phone
permanent_address_zip_code
```

Comment: You should really still put it in a separate table.  In most cases, it is quite useful to have a history of addresses for a user.

Comment: You should design your database to satisfy the business requirements.